# How do I reference the value of multiple cells from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The real kicker here is that I only want to reference certain cells if a cell has been selected.

I am creating a "leads" Spreadsheet on Google. Once a target has been contacted, their information needs to be populated to a different sheet to better track the lead. I am looking for a formula that would only reference the information if a certain cell (or checkbox) is selected.

Example: "A property owner is being sent marketing information from our company; this process is being tracked on Spreadsheet1. If the property owner calls our company, we would put an "X" in the cell titled "Lead Responded" (H2). Once an X is placed in H2, the Owners Name (A2), Address (B2), Phone Number (C2) and Community Name (D2) will be populated into Spreadsheet2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
=FILTER('Spreadsheet 1'!A2:D,'Spreadsheet 1'!H2:H="X")
```